# Only Pushing forces exist right?

Tags: forces

I am a third-year high schooler and I remember Michio Kaku once said (in some documentary which I can't sadly find now) That only pushing forces exist. Pulling a door is actually your fingers pushing it from the other side. Gravity is the curvature of space-time so it is pushing it towards earth. The charges probably push by their electric fields. My question is what is the pushing force in magnets,
Thanks.
[Sorry for bad english]

Comment: I am not sure if it is proven that only pushing forces exists. In your own example, if you go little deeper - Your fingers push the door, but inside your body, your muscles know only to contract, which would be a pull action. Its your muscles that cause your fingers to push on the door. In common sense, attraction sounds more like a pull force and repulsion a push force. Common sense is not to be underestimated. Taking the muscle example, it is possible to generate push based upon underlying pull.

Comment: Fundamental force between quarks seems to be a pull.

Comment: Forces only exist in an approximate version of the laws of physics, they don't really exist in our universe.

Comment: Chandler I think you have the right idea or at least there's nothing wrong with thinking that way. I think they will find there is no force other than push. Just like there is no such thing as suction. It's just a higher pressure pushing in on a lower pressure area. It has definitely not been proven that gravity pulls.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285694/44126

Comment: @kpv Pull because that's the fault in our language. We call it pull if force is being applied from the other side of our Point of View. But just think of that force vector. The source must be at the tail of vector, right ? Doesn't that make sense ?

Comment: @Bill Alsept On the other hand, It has already been proven that gravity pushes by Einstein, as a result of curvature of space-time.

Comment: @rob   I can't tell you how much i owe you, i was trynna find this video so hard, thanks man ^0^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all forces push, some can pull, like gravity or the electrostatic force between oppositely charged particles.  What Michio Kaku probably meant is that only *contact* forces exist: in other words, objects can only affect each other if the are exactly at the same point - they can't exert a force on something far away.  Gravity and electromagnetism might seem to be counterexamples, but you can think of objects interacting via gravity or E&M as exchanging particles called gravitons or photons, respectively, that can't travel faster than the speed of light and "transmit" the force between the two objects.  So when magnets attract, it's because of the exchange of photons traveling between them, and the one magnet is not *directly* influenced by the other magnet, just by the photons "coming out" of it.

Comment: Or you could say mediated by a intermediate fields - spacetime or the EM field, if you want to keep the discussion classical.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Absolutely.  I phrased it in terms of mediator particles because you can picture the two objects exchanging a stream of gravitons/photons like two people on a sheet of ice throwing snowballs at each other.  The analogy's is highly imperfect and potentially misleading, but it's more concrete for a beginner than the more amorphous concept of a field.

Comment: Hey man, gravity is already proven to be a pushing force by Einstein as a result of the curvature of space-time.

Comment: And the existence of gravitons is not yet proved on the other hand. (As far as I know. I heard CERN was making a huge-ass collider to prove their existence and if they do, string theory would be proven.)

Answer (score 2):

In electromagnetism, the force between two electric charges $q_1, q_2$ is
$$
 \vec F = \frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2} \hat r.
$$
There are two types of charge which add, in equal quantities, to zero, so we call them "positive" and "negative" charges.  And what you can see is that same-sign charges feel a repulsive force, along the separation vector $\vec r$, but for opposite-charge particles the direction of the force changes sign and becomes attractive.  I can't think of a way to describe the one    as a "pushing" force but the other not as a "pulling" force.

Magnetism is a side effect of electricity; you can actually find all the rules of magnetism by thinking about electricity and special relativity at the same time.  Magnetism gives you a set of rules about electric currents:

1. Parallel currents ($\uparrow\uparrow$) attract each other.
2. Antiparallel currents ($\uparrow\downarrow$) repel each other.
3. Skewed currents ($\uparrow\rightarrow$) feel a torque that makes them want to align.

For permanent magnets the "current" is actually a single unpaired electron orbiting each atom, or possibly the "spin" of that electron, but that gets a little ways into sneaky territory.

If you want to think in a field picture, you have to consider the fields produced by both source particles. In that case, what you find is the sources of the fields tending to adjust their locations so that the total energy stored in the field (proportional to field strength squared in each little volume unit) is minimized. I have a hard time calling that pulling or pushing, and it's closest to the modern view.

Comment: " I can't think of a way to describe the one as a "pushing" force but the other not as a "pulling" force." Both create an electric field which has the same property for a charge (either to repel or attract, whatever you take by convention) So that field can push it right. Just a way to think about that.

Comment: You call it Pull because that's the fault in our language. We call it pull if force is being applied from the other side of our Point of View. But just think of that force vector. The source must be at the tail of vector, right ? Doesn't that make sense ?

Comment: Yeah, that's more acceptable than most of the comments here.

Comment: @ChandlerBing I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not all forces are pushing forces.  Some are attractive (pulling), such as gravity.

Comment: Hey man, gravity is already proven to be a pushing force by Einstein as a result of the curvature of space-time.

Comment: You call it Pull because that's the fault in our language. We call it pull if force is being applied from the other side of our Point of View. But just think of that force vector. The source must be at the tail of vector, right ? Doesn't that make sense ?

Comment: This might be becoming a discussion of semantics rather than physics.  I use 'pulling' to mean attractive (things coming together) rather than repulsive (things moving apart).  Is matter moving in curved space being 'pulled' or 'pushed'? I'd say those everyday terms don't really apply.

Comment: All I wanna say is, the source of all forces is  at the tail of their force vectors. Gravity is the source of curvature of space-time. The curvature is the source of that "PUSHING" force. The earth isn't the SOURCE of the FORCE, the mass curves space-time and that leads to the force. The source of force being in the direction of the tip vector doesn't seem very intuitive does it ?